# Customising TextView in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am having some trouble with editing the title in my toolbar. I want to style the title and I've been trying some potential solutions which don't work.

I keep getting a null pointer exception when I run the follow code. Any help would be appreciated!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_skill);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String skill = in.getStringExtra("skill");
    String detail = in.getStringExtra("detail");
    String required = in.getStringExtra("required");

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.titleskill);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    toolbarTitle.setText(skill);

    toolbar.setTitleMarginBottom(50);
    //     toolbar.setTitle(skill);
```

Layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="128dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        >

        <TextView android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/titleskill"
            android:maxLines="2"
            >

        </TextView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Null Pointer Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at athena.sentineljs.com.athena.Skill.onCreate(Skill.java:49)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Please add the logcat part where it is showing NPE.

Comment: @code-crusher I've just updated my question, check it out above!

Comment: Are you extending AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @Eenvincible Yes, I am doing that.

Comment: What bout you setting showTitle to false? Can you try to remove it?

Comment: @EenvincibleJust tried that and I got the exact same error I'm afraid.

Comment: I think you are using <TextView> ... </TextView> as ViewGroup. Which will show an error. Use <TextView ... /> :).

Comment: @code-crusher I tried your suggestion but it's not working as well. :/

Comment: @TzenSzenToh are you sure the string _skill_ you are getting is not null? Try with another string. -  toolbarTitle.setText("skill");

Comment: @code-crusher Yes, the string _skill_  is not null. I tried using the string you've suggested and still get the same error.

Comment: @TzenSzenToh why did you write `toolbar.setTitleMarginBottom(50);` this code?

Comment: @ShaishavJogani I wanted more space between the title and the bottom of the toolbar.

Comment: As you have disable title in toolbar by  `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` So, I guess `setTitle` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Include your toolbar layout file inside your activity_skill.xml using include tag like this

`<include layout="@layout/<your toolbar file name>"/>`

Example: if your toolbar layout file name is toolbar.xml your include tag should look like this, without the .xml extension

`<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>`

Comment: Hmm... The toolbar is displaying fine, just that the textview inside it can't be altered. Sorry, I'm not sure how this solution would help could you elaborate further please?

Comment: remove this atrribute android:textSize="50dp" from the TextView inside the <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>. Also use 'sp' for text sizes not 'dp'

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I've just solved the problem. Cheers! :)